Minor design issue in Profile Activity section on SE
When I hover over adjacent items in the Activity section's sidebar, the background colors seem to blend or overlap slightly. Is this the intended design?


This appears to be the intended design, however, I think you have found a bug on this particular page, (Activity), because on other pages with similar menus, the selected menu item appears on a blue background here on MSE.
Here are some screenshots showing the effect when selecting questions from the activity page and then hovering over other menu options:

You can see that the Tags and Following menu items are highlighted when hovering over them. However, the background to the Questions menu item is light grey as well, whereas on the Settings and Saves page the background of the selected menu item is blue, for example:

These screenshots are from MSE, but it appears that this situation occurs on other sites as well.
If you inspect the selected menu item in the developer console, then you will notice that the ul element has a s-navigation__muted style applied:

Removing this style from this element makes it possible to see the correct background highlighting:

